# How to make H1 tag responsive in Avada WordPress theme using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

My friend is using the Avada WordPress theme, and has currently upgraded the latest version of WordPress (via the admin panel I assume as no physical files have been uploaded).

His page titles (H1) are no longer responsive as they were before he upgraded. The title stays the full width of the page when resizing the browser.

This is how the header is placed on the top of the page (within the admin):

```
[fullwidth backgroundcolor="no" backgroundimage="" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="left top" backgroundattachment="scroll" bordersize="0px" bordercolor="" borderstyle="solid" paddingtop="0px" paddingbottom="0px" paddingleft="0px" paddingright="0px" menu_anchor="" class="big_title" id=""][four_fifth last="no" class="" id=""][title size="1" content_align="left" style_type="single" sep_color="#ffffff" class="" id=""]H1 PAGE TITLE HERE[/title][/four_fifth][one_fifth last="yes" class="" id=""][button link="http://www.arttouchesart.com/about/" color="custom" size="medium" type="flat" shape="square" target="_self" title="" gradient_colors="#ffffff|#ffffff" gradient_hover_colors="#000000|#000000" accent_color="#000000" accent_hover_color="#ffffff" bevel_color="" border_width="2px" shadow="no" icon="" icon_position="left" icon_divider="no" modal="" animation_type="0" animation_direction="left" animation_speed="1" alignment="right" class="" id=""]ABOUT[/button][/one_fifth]
```

I have located the big_title class within the CSS, which is in a custom.css file:

```
.big_title h1 {
font-size:56px;
line-height:56px;
text-align:left!important;
}
```

Is there a simple CSS trick to allow the H1 to re-size once the browser is made smaller?

Comment: change the px to em and see if that works ?

Comment: Tried that also, but did not work... it's an odd one as stays the full width... the text on the page which falls within the fullwidth tag is responsive, but the H1 seems to just stay at full width.

Comment: You have to use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) and `font-size:n%;` *(`n` is a number between 0 and 100 in %)*.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the H1 code, as I have tried just about every trick possible.. as I mentioned, it worked before my friend upgraded to latest WordPress... the website coding is a mess, and hard to find what goes where... frustrating, and I think this one has defeated me! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the rest of the styling, it would be difficult to say how to do this neatly. But, you could try:

```
.big_title h1 {
    /* All your other CSS here */
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Note - I've added the `!important` declaration, only as a fail safe. Test it first without, and do not include it if it works. If it doesn't work, add it and see if that helps.

If still no joy, you'll need to right click on the h1 tag (in your web browser) and then click "Inspect" (assuming you're using Google Chrome, there will be a similar feature in IE, Firefox and Safari). You'll then need to use Element Inspector to look at the CSS properties being applied to that tag and work out how to override them in your custom.css file (like we've just attempted).

Comment: I have just tried that, and even added max-width: 100% to every DIV element, and it still does not work.

Comment: OK - as I said, it's difficult to understand what's causing the problem without further information. Have you had a look in element inspector to see the CSS properties being applied?

Comment: I checked the website using Chrome, and did the Inspect as you mentioned... added max-width: 100% to every DIV element it is within or associated with and it's still not working. This has baffled me big time!

Comment: That wasn't what I suggested.
You need to see all of the style attributes applied to that element (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/KAJPIQb.png) - bottom right corner).

This will tell you what is going on. If you're confused - copy (or screenshot) them into your original question.